# OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I've seen plenty of samples/examples in the Android documentation about using OpenGL ES 1.x with Android, but I can't seem to find *anything* about using OpenGL ES 2.x with Android.

[In one of his presentations](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-62tRHLcHk), Chris Pruett from Google says to always try to use OpenGL ES 2.x over 1.x, but I don't even know where to start learning on how to create a proper template...

Can someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

- [GLES20Activity.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/GLES20Activity.html)
- [GLES20TriangleRenderer.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/GLES20TriangleRenderer.html)

Answer (score 0):

i'm also started learning Es20 on android

and i'm posting my progess in my blog

and code i'm putting in google code

if you are interested you can look at below links

[BLOG](http://opengles2learning.blogspot.com/)

[CODE](http://code.google.com/p/sravan-work/)

i'm trying to make it as comprehensive help